# OpenVPN - How to suppress WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this

Tags: vpn, openvpn, configuration, password-management, warning

In **OpenVPN GUI**, I am getting the red message

> WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this.

I do *not* want to always re-type my password again and again. Is there a way to **suppress** the warning **without** using the `auth-nocache` option?

I do not want to get myself used to habitually ignoring a red warning in the log dialog. This bad habit might prevent me from noticing an actual issue in the future. We have `@SuppressWarning` in Java for exactly the same reason.

I want to emphasize that I am not choosing between security and convenience, but I am asking for *higher security*! Multiple internet sources I found on this warning (e.g. [here](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202720436-Auth-nocache-Warning-in-OpenVPN-connection-log), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307509/204770) or [here](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/troubleshooting/log-items/configuration-cache-passwords/)) tell that the risk is minimal. However the risk that I become used to ignore warnings seems much higher to me.

Comment: Why won't you just *ignore* this warning?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov It's called "no warning policy". Getting used to ignoring warnings is a bad habit. Either **solve** or **suppress** a warning (after you understand its meaning and consequences), but **never ignore**. Some companies, e.g. Google, have even set their compilers to report all warnings as errors and break the build, so the developers don't get used to ignoring warnings.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov OpenVPN GUI shows the log while connecting and warnings are displayed in red. I want to stay able to catch visually something wrong. If I get used to seeing the red color every time I am connecting, I will lose this sense. And I will overlook a real problem. Not letting users or admins to suppress individual warnings is a bad design and it goes against security.

Comment: A-ha, I remember, the same stupid policy lead to the introduction of [CVE-2008-0166](https://github.com/g0tmi1k/debian-ssh) in Debian. They broken the PRNG by *resolving or silencing Valgrind warnings* in the OpenSSL source.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Actually the case mentioned here is yet another argument for my statement :) Instead of suppressing the warning (with the comment in the code that the warning here is OK), they removed the code causing the warning. That's **not** what *no-warning policy* means, this is suboptimization instead. They indeed silenced the warning...

Comment: @HonzaZidek I completely agree. I upvoted the question, as I'm having the same concerns as you do.